# Getting at LinkedIn returned data from Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

What I'd like to do is get at the returned data from the LinkedIn API named `data` from the function named `getProfileData`. How can I access the data that contains the information such as `firstName` and `lastName` but in `getProfileData` and not just in the function `onSuccess`?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key: YOUR_API_KEY_HERE
    authorize: true
    onLoad: onLinkedInLoad
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    // Setup an event listener to make an API call once auth is complete
    function onLinkedInLoad() {
        IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", getProfileData);
    }

    // Handle the successful return from the API call
    function onSuccess(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }

    // Handle an error response from the API call
    function onError(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

    // Use the API call wrapper to request the member's basic profile data
    function getProfileData() {
        IN.API.Raw("/people/~").result(onSuccess).error(onError);
        // I want to see the profile data in here. 

    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must fix something in your code :

```
IN.API.Raw("/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,location,positions)?format=json").result(onSuccess).error(onError);
```

Comment: data.firstName, data.lastName in onSuccess function